# JMockit and Jacoco Java 5

Tags: java, jmockit

I see in version JMockit 1.8 support for Jacoco was fixed, however this also went hand in hand with making Java 6 a minimum requirement.

Is there a way of getting version 1.8 to work with a build runtime of Java 5? Or even patching the fix for Jacoco into version 1.7? What changed, could I do it?

We can't upgrade our build servers for a few months, so this would really help us use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 6 as compiler, and make a war 1.5 compliant. Anyway, the tests are not deployed on server side.... (Or I hope so)

Comment: Hi, Sadly we cannot update our servers to 6 even during build. I was hoping I could just patch in the jacoco fix.